# Kubernetes: extract environment variables from a file when pod kicked off

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to know whether I'm able to propagate environment variables from a file.

Guess I have a file like this:

```
ENV_VARIABLE_USERNAME=username
ENV_VARIABLE_PASSWORD=password
```

I'd like when I pod kicks off, this content file is propagated as environment variables.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, for environment variables, you would do it through a configMap. But as this is a username and password (sensitive information), you can do it through a secret.

For example, given the Pod (redis, for this example) and the Secret below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  username: dXNlcm5hbWU=        //username -> encoded base64
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=        //password -> encoded base64
```

Note: you need to have all data in a secret encoded. This one is encoded with base64:

```
echo -n username | base64
```

And the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: credentials
            key: username
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: credentials
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Now if you would run `env | grep SECRET` in the pod, I would get the variable correctly initialized:

```
nerus:~/workspace (master) $ kubectl exec redis-pod env | grep SECRET
SECRET_USERNAME=username
SECRET_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `j2cli` and Jinja templates for my Kubernetes manifests. The manifests are written as Jinja templates and j2cli can pass the env vars for me:

```
j2 --format=env config.j2 data.env
```

https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli

Comment: Would you mind provinding how to use this instruction into my spec file?

Answer (score 0):

If your Kubernetes version is higher than 1.6, you can configure your file as a ConfigMap :

`kubectl create configmap yourconfigmap --from-env-file=YOUR_ENV_FILE`

and then use the content of the configmap in [your pod as environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-pod-environment-variables)

```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: yourpod
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: test-container
         image: yourimage
         command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
         envFrom:
         - configMapRef:
             name: yourconfigmap
     restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: `YOUR_ENV_FILE` can be a file on container filesystem?

Comment: following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/federation/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1_envfromsource), envFrom is either a configmap or a secret ref . `YOUR_ENV_FILE` is outside the container and injected in the container as environment variable through `configMap` or `secret` like suren's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983027/2653911) show.